# Will mozactivity work with in android using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, firefox-os

I have created an application for Firefox OS. This application uses MOZActivity ( calling, sending message ) and working fine in Firefox OS. But now I want to convert it to phonegap so I can release this application for android. 
My question is, I use mozacitvity to send msg and to call, will it work on Android using phonegap?

I don't know much about phonegap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain your question more?

Comment: Suppose in my application i have a button when user press this button a message need to send a specified number. To do this i use mozactivity ( message activity that present with the system) to handle send message with my specific value( message body and sender number) then everything handle  by system. This work fine. As i know i can convert my application for android and iOS using phonegap but i dont know this feature (mozactivity) which is working great in firefox will work in android .

Comment: mozactivity is mozilla only, you can't use that on other platforms

Answer (score 0):

I seriously  doubt it. 
Take a look at:
SMS: http://javatechig.com/cross-platform/phonegap/phonegap-sms-plugin-android
Calls: http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/

Just change your code to Phonegap, it supports Firefox OS as well:
http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/22/firefox-os-phones-for-phonegap-developers/

good luck

Comment: Is this work with firefox OS or i need to build separate application . However thanks for this link @Rui Lima

Comment: just use phonegap for everything.